# AJAX query: load the page, before success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently trying to make a post request using AJAX:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://....',
  type: 'post',
  data: {test:'val', studentAnswer:'val'},
  success: function(data, status, jq_xhr) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

However, the page I'm trying to get is an HTML page that has to load JavaScript. The problem is that I can not load the page, and I want only to get the response, not the entire source code of the page.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the URL you're reaching out to is set up to take POST requests.

**Can you share the URL you are hitting?**

If you also manage the server - create a method to handle POST requests not to return an HTML file. If the endpoint you are reaching out to is a webpage, it will always return the source HTML file.

Here's an example:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://requestbin.fullcontact.com/qq3wmoqq",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "data": "{test:'val', studentAnswer:'val'}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

To check the actual request going through:
https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/qq3wmoqq?inspect

Comment: The web page I am reaching is a HTML file, I can't do otherwise. What I'm doing is that I want to use the data sent to make a JS command, and then display it. And it is this reponse only that I want, a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try put your code in **document ready**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
...here your code..
})
```